# Im not able to build ionic android project...it gives me a error : spawn cmd enoent

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Not able to build or add android and install android platform in ionic project 
It gives me error: spawn cmd Enoent.
Im not able run ionic project as im not able to build it

Answer (score 0):

Add the path `C:\Windows\System32;.....` and recheck once again where are you trying to create the project and try to create a project it will work.